# Some CSS styles in FreeMarker template are not applied to PDF generated by FlyingSaucer

Tags: java, freemarker, flying-saucer

I'm trying to create a PDF with FlyingSaucer and Apache FreeMarker as template engine.
Although the HTML template generated looks fine when opened with browser, some styles seemed to not applied to the created PDF.

I have a CSS class that set height to 100% -

```
    .someClass::before{
        content:"";
        border-left: thin solid;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
    }

    .someClass:last-child::before{
        height: 10px;
    }
```

The last-child::before pseudo-element styles works fine in both HTML and PDF, however .someClass::before rendered as if the `height: 100%` is excluded.

I have tried added `html, body { height: 100% }` as others suggested but to no avail.